# Oracle SQL MERGE Statement using multiple COLUMN_VALUE keywords

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am doing a MERGE statement using Oracle SQL. I have a procedure which has 1 input parameter as a VARCHAR2 and 2 input parameters which are simple custom types. Please see the code below:

```
procedure proc_1
(
    in_param_1 IN VARCHAR2,
    in_param_array_1 IN CUSTOM_ARRAY_TYPE,
    in_param_array_2 IN CUSTOM_ARRAY_TYPE
)
as
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSCATION

    BEGIN

    MERGE INTO table T
    USING (SELECT in_param_1 param_1, COLUMN_VALUE array_col1 FROM TABLE(in_param_array_1), COLUMN_VALUE array_col2 FROM TABLE (in_param_array_2)) S
    ON (T.col1 = S.param_1)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    ...
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    ...
```

Custom type definition:

```
TYPE CUSTOM_ARRAY_TYPE
AS
TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4);
```

The problem arises when I am trying to use 2 COLUMN_VALUE keywords in the SELECT portion of the MERGE statement. If I only use 1 COLUMN_VALUE, for example like below, there's no issue and it compiles fine:

```
USING (SELECT in_param_1 param_1, COLUMN_VALUE array_col1 FROM TABLE(in_param_array_1)) S
```

The actual error I am getting is this:

```
Missing right parenthesis
```

How can I include both of my custom type array input parameters so that I can use the values they store later in my MERGE statement?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. You merge on `T.col1 = S.param_1`. This means that your `USING` query should have one row per `param_1`. But it doesn't. You select it as many times as there are elements in `in_param_array_1`. Now you seem to even  try to cross join `in_param_array_1` with `in_param_array_2`, thus producing even more rows with `param_1`. What are you really trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your USING clause should be:

```
SELECT in_param_1 param_1, x1.COLUMN_VALUE array_col1,x2.COLUMN_VALUE array_col2 
  FROM TABLE(in_param_array_1) x1, 
       TABLE(in_param_array_2) x2
```

That should work syntactically but you will get a Cartesian product between the two arrays, as there is no joinable column between them. While you could risk generating one in an inline block with ROWNUM, that's not very safe. The only way to safely join the right element in one to the same element in the other is either in PL/SQL or by using a collection of object with named fields, one of which would be a sequence number that ties your columns together across your collections. Then you would include that in your join, and you wouldn't need COLUMN_VALUE since you would have real column names to work with.